# sending user back to previous page after submitting web form on current page, .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, webforms

On a .net site, is there an easy way to send someone back to the last page they were on before they posted back a form on the current page without some sort of overwrought breadcrumb system? I know that sounds a bit confusing, but lets say you're on Page1.aspx. You go to Page2.aspx, which has a web form. You fill out the web form which posts back to itself. After the postback, I want to send them back to whatever page they were on first, in this case : Page1.aspx. Page1.aspx is obviously variable.

I started playing with some javascript using history.go(), but I wasn't able to get it to work properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Request.UrlReferrer Property as described here:

[Navigate to Previous Page in ASP.NET(Request.UrlReferrer)](http://sherasdotnet.blogspot.com/2011/10/navigate-to-previous-page-in.html)

Comment: I understand this approach as well, but it requires saving the previous page in the ViewState. I'm trying to avoid that type of programming (since there are ALOT of pages that could be the referrer) by attempting to utilize the DOM directly.

Comment: The ViewState size per page for this would be minimal. Do a trace on it and see. You are only saving the page name in ViewState, not the page itself.

Comment: Ah, I got it working. I thought I was going to have to set the ViewState on every referring page, which would have been alot of work. Instead, I set the ViewState on Page2.aspx to whatever was in Request.UrlReferrer. Then redirected back to it after the postback. This definitely got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the page that must return as a url parameter, just like login module do.

Eg, you go to the `page2.aspx` with this url `page2.aspx?RetPage=Page1.aspx` and when you finish with the page2, you get the `RetPage` and redirect to whatever value you have set there.

Comment: Same with this.. it requires me leaving a trail, or a breadcrumb to track back. It's completely feasible, it would just require me going through alot of pages and adding this in.

Comment: @optionsix You can try and others but they are not 100% guarantee that they always work.

Comment: yeah I know... I was hoping there would be a shortcut, but I know this is a good fallback, if a bit grunt-worky.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the [referrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) (Page1.aspx) to Page2.aspx. Page2.aspx then uses a hidden input-field, containing the referrer.
When the visitor submits the form from Page2 (to itself), the form-handler then receives the referrer and could set it as a `http-equiv="refresh"` in the resulting page.

```
<html>    
  <head>      
    <title>Form Result</title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='Page1.aspx'" />    
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <p>Thank you for your input, you will automatically return to
       <a href="Page1.aspx/">the previous page in 5 seconds.</a>.</p> 
  </body>  
</html>
```

By changing the timeout to more than 0 seconds the user can still read the result before he is automatically sent back to the page he came from.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand this approach, but it would require me passing the referrer, which is still a breadcrumb. "Page1.aspx" could be any of 50 different referring pages, each of which I'd have to program in the referrer, unless I'm incorrect about that?

Comment: Yes, you get the referrer from the server (like a variable), you do not have to code a list of each and every referring page.